# Python: weird set comprehension: partial apply? implicit carrying?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Consider the line from concurrent.futures example ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example ):

```
future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
```

Don't get the idea what's exactly going on her **executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url**. Evidently, it is set comprehension and **executor.submit** is applied to every **url** in **URLS**. But what technique is used to fix **load_url** and **60** parameters?? That is some kind of curriyng or partial apply using column operator, but what language feature is it??

Comment: It's a dictionary comprehension, not a set comprehension, thus the `:`

Comment: Little notice: this is a dictionary comprehension :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Evidently, it is set comprehension

No, it's a dict comprehension. The expression before the colon is each new key, and the expression after is the corresponding value.

Answer (score 1):

`load_url` is a method defined just above (`load_url(url, timeout)`).

I guess `executor.submit(load_url,url,60)` calls at some point `load_url(url,60)`.
So 60 is the timeout (probably because 60s=1mn).

The dictionary comprehension applies `executor.submit` to every url with the same two parameters `load_url` and `60`, and one changing parameter `url`.

Comment: Yes, that is **dictionary** comprehension. Thanks )))

Comment: Was **that** your question ? I thought it was "what technique is used to fix load_url and 60 parameters ?", and my answer is: there's not technique, they are just fixed.